# Is there a JavaScript style Collection in Java

Tags: javascript, java, collections

In JavaScript I can define the following collection with keys awaiting values

```
var items = {
                'book':null,
                'pen':null,
                'pencil':null,
                'chicken':null,
                'wallet':null
            };
```

Then when I am ready to add values to my collection, I can do for instance

```
for(var p in items){
  if(some condition){
     items[p]=someValue;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this with the same level of efficiency in java?

I know that in old Java I can combine a Map and a List to accomplish this, but are their new data structures in Java that can handle this? I am talking about Java 7 (or 8) perhaps? I am using Google App-Engine for my Java.

Comment: Note that you don't actually have to initialize JavaScript object properties. If you make an assignment to a non-existent property, the property is added to the object.

Comment: I dont understand the question I guess, but are you [asking for this?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)

Comment: So I have edited to drive the point home: I am iterating before adding any values to the collection.

Comment: Updated my answer with regards to your latest comments.

Comment: Since the two answers are essentially the same, I will check the first response and up vote the second one. Thank you very much for helping resolve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT: Updated my answer based on the latest comments.**

You could perfectly use a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) to achieve the same effect. To iterate over the existing keys, use the `Map#keySet` method.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("book", null);
map.put("pen", null);

for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    map.put(key, "Some Value");
}

System.out.println(map);
```

Comment: ...and, starting with Java 7, you can use the diamond notation: Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

Comment: The answers are the same, but this answer was first. So I up vote the other and check this one.

Answer (score 6):

You could try it this way, if you're looking for the same style.

```
 HashMap<String, String > items  = new HashMap<String, String>(){{
        put("book",null);
        put("pen",null);
    }};
```

Later you can put again with keys.

```
items.put("book", "Some Bible");
```

It seems you are new to Java and both Collections. I'm highly recommend you to read the about HashMap more before proceeding.

Comment: This is more what OP was asking for I think

Comment: Although, to be honest, I don't see the point of putting those keys with a null value. The value null will be returned anyway, by getting "book", if it's not present in the map.

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox True. But I don't exactly know why OP is looking that way and. One benefit I can see is `containsKey()` method behaviour.

Comment: This looks like a bad idea to me. Creating an anonymous class extending HashMap just to avoid using `items.` in front of `put`?

Comment: I suppose this is closer to what I was looking for, although it does in fact reduce to a Map and a List. You may be overlooking what is actually happening in my for-loop, where I am iterating over the keys essentially. So I suppose your answer works if I use `items.keySet()` to get the keys. Perhaps this is as close as it gets.

Comment: @BrentC I'm with you here. That's just a hack almost, not good practise though.

Comment: @KatedralPillon the JavaScript example is also no different than a Map. (I don't see where a List figures into any of this.)

Comment: @BrentC that's a common pattern; the subclass does nothing but add an initializer block. That way the whole thing is a single expression instead of a list of separate statements.

Comment: In the javascript example I am iterating before I put any values to the collection: it only contains keys. I can reformat the question to make that clear. But then it is clear as it is as I am making an assignment right inside of my loop.

Comment: @KatedralPillon Yes there are multiple ways to iterate but just go for that keySet way as of now.